# Custom serialization from Record to JSON

Tags: json, record, ballerina

I have the following Ballerina code snippet:

```
import ballerina/io;

type Date record {|
    string year;
    string month?;
    string day?;
|};

public function main() {

    Date birthDate = {
        year: "1980",
        month: "6",
        day: "20"
    };

    io:print(birthDate.toJson());
}
```

The default `JSON` representation of the Date record is as follows:

```
{
    "year": "1980",
    "month": "6",
    "day": "20"
}
```

My question is, can we manipulate this default `JSON` representation of `birthDate` into a custom representation like the one below, while keeping the record type Date as it is?

```
{
   "birthdate": "1980-6-20"
}
```

Is there a way to customize the `JSON` serialization of the Date record in Ballerina to achieve this specific format?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is first transform the shape of this Date record to a new shape. Then use that transformed value to get the json. In the below example, `transformBirthdayRecord` function will to the shape transformation.

```
public function main() {

    Date birthDate = {
        year: "1980",
        month: "6",
        day: "20"
    };

    io:print(transformBirthdayRecord(birthDate).toJson());
}

function transformBirthdayRecord(Date date) returns record {|string birthdate;|} {
    string birthdate = date.year;
    string? month = date.month;
    string? day = date.day;
    if month is string && day is string {
        birthdate += string `-${month}-${day}`;
    }
    return {birthdate};
};
```